# effective way to generate thumbnail from uiimage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, cpu, thumbnails

I have an UICollectionView and each item shows a square image. 
Each image is big file (> 3MB) and every time app try to jump into this view. It will delay 2-3 seconds. 
I try to create a thumbnail from big file then apply to each collection item. But it seems not saving time.

Is there any effective way ?

Follow is the method I use to create thumbnail

```
-(UIImage*)resizedImageToSize:(CGSize)dstSize{
CGImageRef imgRef = self.CGImage;
// the below values are regardless of orientation : for UIImages from Camera, width>height (landscape)
CGSize  srcSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef)); // not equivalent to self.size (which is dependant on the imageOrientation)!

/* Don't resize if we already meet the required destination size. */
if (CGSizeEqualToSize(srcSize, dstSize)) {
    return self;
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = dstSize.width / srcSize.width;
UIImageOrientation orient = self.imageOrientation;
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.width, srcSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, srcSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.height, srcSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, srcSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The actual resize: draw the image on a new context, applying a transform matrix
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(dstSize, NO, self.scale);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (!context) {
    return nil;
}

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -srcSize.height, 0);
} else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -srcSize.height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

// we use srcSize (and not dstSize) as the size to specify is in user space (and we use the CTM to apply a scaleRatio)
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, srcSize.width, srcSize.height), imgRef);
UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return resizedImage;
```

}

Comment: Where do you get the source UIImages from in the first place? Are they read from file or network?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I read them from local file

Answer (score 4):

There's a built in way to create thumbnails from compressed image files: directly using ImageIO. It is lightning fast compared to rendering the image into a smaller bitmap context.

Here's a method that does the job:

```
+ (UIImage *)thumbnailWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)URL maxPixelSize:(CGFloat)maxPixelSize
{
    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)URL, NULL);
    NSAssert(imageSource != NULL, @"cannot create image source");

    NSDictionary *imageOptions = @{
        (NSString const *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent : (NSNumber const *)kCFBooleanTrue,
        (NSString const *)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize            : @(maxPixelSize),
        (NSString const *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform     : (NSNumber const *)kCFBooleanTrue
    };
    CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)imageOptions);
    CFRelease(imageSource);

    UIImage *result = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnail];
    CGImageRelease(thumbnail);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to create a thumbnail that's square... with a fixed size? Cause I only see a kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize?!?